# Are circular groups allowed by XSD schema?

Tags: xsd, xsd.exe, circular-reference

For this xml:

```
<elem1 xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0">
 <elem2>
   <elem2/>
 </elem2>
</elem1>
```

I have this schema, which seems to validate fine against [w3 schema validation service](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv), and the schema validates the above XML just fine. Sadly, xsd.exe and some other tools report it to be an error. Is that correct? Are circular group refs dissallowed by XML schema? Thanks!

Update: The schema is not mine, can't change it :(

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0" xmlns:t="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0">

  <xs:element name="elem1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:group ref="t:grp1" />
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:group name="grp1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="t:grp2" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:group name="grp2">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="elem2">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:group ref="t:grp1" />
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: What is the error from xsd.exe?

Comment: Error: Error generating classes for schema 'tmp'.
  - Group 'grp2' from targetNamespace='...' has invalid definition: Circular group reference.
If this is an XSD error, I could try to contact the organization responsible for it, and tell them of a bug. If not, I will try to find an alternative code generator, or try to fix the bug in mono's xsd.exe (which hangs instead of showing an error).

Answer (score 2):

It's a legal scheme. Problem is that xsd is trying to traverse all dependencies. The MS version preprocesses scheme and expands all groups. Because of the cyclic dependency such expansion would be infinite so it quits with an error. With the Mono version there are two probable scenarios:

1. It tries to traverse dependency tree
   and ends up in an infinite loop.
2. It tries to expand all groups and
   ends up in an infinite loop.

That is just my guess. I never saw actual source codes of Mono xsd.

Comment: Microsoft's response at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637855 was that this is not a valid schema. Could you elaborate? I suspect they are wrong, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

This question is being linked with many recent questions that talk about the same problem: circular groups, and Microsoft's xsd.exe, hence I think it should be answered, even though it is quite "old".

The confusion is caused by what qualifies as a circular group. According to section [3.8.6 of the XSD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#coss-modelGroup) spec:

> "Circular groups are disallowed. That is, within the {particles} of a
>   group there must not be at any depth a particle whose {term} is the
>   group itself."

Based on the above, your example **is not** a circular group, since the group itself does not rely on itself **as a particle**. Your schema **is valid**.

**This is a circular group:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="elem1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:group ref="grp1"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:group name="grp1">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:group ref="grp1"/>
            </xsd:choice>                       
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:group>
</xsd:schema>
```

One cannot rewrite a true circular group. However, your example can be rewritten in a couple of ways: the schema below shows an equivalent content model, based on recursive complex types.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xmlns="">Generated from "Set1" under "Release2"</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:complexType name="grp1">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="elem2" type="grp1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="elem1" type="grp1"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

It is also "entertaining" to see that the following schema actually works with xsd.exe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.fixprotocol.org/ns/fast/t/1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xmlns="">Generated from "Set1" under "Release2"</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:element name="elem1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:group ref="grp1"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:group name="grp1">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="elem2">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:group ref="grp1"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:group>
</xsd:schema>
```

From an XML instance perspective, all three valid schemas are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the tools you are using don't support all possibilities supported by the XML schema spec. Certainly xsd.exe doesn't support everything. The spec is gigantic and it isn't worth providing mappings from everything it supports into a programming language, particularly when some things just don't map very well.

To work around this, you could try to create a set of C# classes that mimic the xml you want to generate and then run xsd.exe on those classes to generate an xsd. There is probably some other XML schema construct that supports what you want.

Comment: Yes David, that is the issue, but I need to find out if it is allowed by XSD spec or not, and possibly help Mono team resolve this (their xsd.exe tool hangs). I wish I could change the schema, but as usual - it is public schema from an organization, not mine :).  I tried to read the spec, but got very confused by their language, so was hoping someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about groups but XSD.exe supports circular elements:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Class1" nillable="true" type="Class1" />
  <xs:complexType name="Class1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="child" type="Class1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```