# Circular reference error while trying to import WSDL into Visual Studio 2013

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, xsd, wsdl, siri-xml

When importing the WSDL file that describes a [SIRI web service](http://user47094.vs.easily.co.uk/siri/) in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, I get an error:

> Warning   5
>   Custom tool warning: Fault named FaultName in operation GetProductionTimetable cannot be imported. Unsupported WSDL, the fault message part must reference an element. This fault message does not reference an element. If you have edit access to the WSDL document, you can fix the problem by referencing a schema element using the 'element' attribute. C:\path\to\TransportationDemo\TransportationDemo\Service References\ServiceReference\Reference.svcmap   1

When using [a modified version of the WSDL, created by the Israeli Ministry of Transporation](http://he.mot.gov.il/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2243:pub-trn-memchakim&catid=167:pub-trn-dev-info&Itemid=304), which cuts out a lot of methods, I get another error (among other errors):

> Warning   5
>   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
>   Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Group 'ServiceDeliveryBodyGroup' from targetNamespace='http://www.siri.org.uk/siri' has invalid definition: Circular group reference.
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://new.webservice.namespace']/wsdl:portType[@name='SOAP-Port']    C:\path\to\TransportationDemo\TransportationDemo\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap  1

It seems that some of the element definitions appear in more than one XSD. So I tried to use `svcutil.exe` to create the proxy code manually. I added file by file required for the dependencies. At first, I had a choice which file to add, `siri.xsd` or `siri\siri_base-v1.3.xsd`, as they both contain definitions of the `ServiceRequestStructure` element.

In the `siri.xsd` path, I add all dependencies and end up with the same circular reference mentioned above.

In the `siri\siri_base-v1.3.xsd` I can actually get code generated. I can create a `SOAPPortClient` object instance. I would like to invoke the `GetStopMonitoringServiceRequest` method on it. But for me to be able to input required fields, I need an instance of a `StopMonitoringRequestStructure` object. This is defined in `siri_stopMonitoring_service.xsd` file, and was not included in the list of XSDs used to generate this proxy. When I *do* add this schema file, I have to add `siri_stopTimetable_service.xsd` too (for the definition of `MonitoringRefStructure`), and then the circular dependency error message from above appears again.

I'm at a loss here, and would appreciate help from someone with more experience in WSDL with Visual Studio, or just SOAP services in general (or this one in particular), to solve this issue.

Please note that SIRI presents web service interfaces in two separate files,  `siri_wsProducer.wsdl` and `siri_wsConsumer.wsdl`. I'm interested in interfacing with the "Producer", as far as I can understand.

This question is related -- it's apparently by a fellow developer, who I would very much be thankful if he participates in this discussion, as he seems to have found a solution:
[Importing WSDL into a .NET project only creates an empty namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229929/importing-wsdl-into-a-net-project-only-creates-an-empty-namespace)

Comment: I tried both the first SIRI link and the second Israeli link, neither contain a WSDL file. Can you update with the proper links so we can check the WSDL?

Comment: Thanks @Abel. Actually both sites contain WSDL files. Here's a [direct link to the original SIRI schemas](http://user47094.vs.easily.co.uk/siri/schema/1.3/siri-1.3.zip) and a [direct link to the modified Israeli MOT schemas](http://media.mot.gov.il/PDF/HE_TRAFFIC_PUBLIC/ANHAYIOT/SIRI-ISRAEL.zip)

Comment: Tx. I believe you, but my Yiddish (if that's what it is) is not very good.

Comment: I tried importing the schemas, received the same errors (so it is reproducible, so much is sure), but after playing with it for a while, the sheer complexity of these schemas did not readily reveal their issues. I'm sorry, but this may be a research question and for that, I lack the time...

Comment: @Abel - thanks for the input and the effort. It's useful to know it's reproducible. Hopefully, someone else would have already experienced & solved these issues, as this is a supposedly "serious" protocol.

Comment: The wsdl are good, the import tool Microsoft uses has some flaws, I've seen it happen with much simpler schemas...

Comment: I'm actually trying everything and every tool I've been using is having problems. Java's Axis2 fails (`The referenced element '{http://www.siri.org.uk/siri}Extensions' was not found!`), Python's pysimplesoap fails (`'NoneType' object is not iterable`), Python's suds fails (`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`). The only thing that seems to work for me right now is Python's SOAPpy, but that doesn't have proper documentation... But I will continue trying!

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you found (you can answer your own q.). While I checked the WSDL for soundness in syntax, I didn't check each and every dependency. If you load the XSD's one by one in a good XSD designer tool like oXygen or Liquid XML, maybe you spot an inconsistency and can fix it at that level.

Comment: @Abel, I just figured where the circularity comes from. Hopefully, I also found a way to fix it. Once I test it (at some point *after* I get a good night sleep), and hopefully it works, I'll also accept it. Thank you for your help and for keeping me focused on actually tracking down the circular reference!

Answer (score 2):

I have played a little more with your schemas and WSDL and found an answer to your issue, although you may not like it...

- There is no difference in [unchecking the re-use types checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872865/what-does-this-wcf-error-mean-custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdlporttype?rq=1), because that only applies to situations where you re-import the definitions
- After import, Visual Studio places all XSD's under the service reference (click "show hidden files"). Select `siri.xsd` and it will show you that it cannot locate two includes.
- To fix the include-issue, I changed the include URI to an absolute URI. This resolved the issue with Visual Studio not being able to locate the files and it then copies them properly.
- When now rebuilding, it will show in the Debug Output window the proper validation errors. Most importantly, it complains about redefinitions. I managed to resolve this by removing any reference to `xml.xsd` and simplifying the few places where it was used (`xml:lang` only). Next thing I did was to place all XSD's directly under the root and fixed all references in `xsl:import` and `xsl:include` to reflect this. Many redefinition errors now disappeared
- It now complains about an `xs:group` being circular (it did so before, but I wanted other warnings to be out of the way):

  > Microsoft.ServiceModel.targets(113,5): error : Group 'ServiceDeliveryBodyGroup' from targetNamespace='http://www.siri.org.uk/siri' has invalid definition: Circular group reference.

  This is a tricky one, because I didn't manage to track why it is considered circular, but if it is, [this is allowed in XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048945/are-circular-groups-allowed-by-xsd-schema). It gets imported twice, but that does not seem to be the cause, I think this is deliberate.

After some further searches, it appears that Microsoft's `xsd.exe`, which is similar to the code used by `wsdl.exe`, `svcutil` and *add a service reference*, has acknowledged this [to be a limitation of their XSD-to-object mapping tools](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637855/xsd-exe-fails-to-handle-circular-group-references).

I think your best bet is to take that group and make it non-circular. After that, it should accept the schemas as valid and proceed. The fact that the importer complains about `wsdl:portType` does not point you in the right direction. It complains about that, because it fails to map all types, which results in mapping no types at all, after which also `wsdl:portType` is unknown, hence the error.

*It is very well possible that the other steps outlined above become obsolete after you fix the `ServiceDeliveryBodyGroup` type. The other errors were actually warnings, and I believe that Microsoft essentially ignores such redefinitions anyway and will proceed "normally".*

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the circular reference goes like this:

- The `ServiceDeliveryStructure complexType` is based on
- `ProducerResponseStructure`, which is based on
- the **`abstract ResponseStructure conplexType`** but contains
- `SiriServiceDeliveryGroup group`, which contains
- `StopMonitoringDelivery element`, which may be substituted for
- the `abstract AbstractFunctionalServiceDelivery element`, which may be substituted for
- the `abstract AbstractResponse element` which is of
- again, the **`abstract ResponseStructure complexType`**

hence the circularity.

The way I discovered this is by commenting out each component of the implicated group, `ServiceDeliveryBodyGroup`. It referenced a few `element`s which had both their `type` (referencing some `complexType`) and `substitutionGroup` (referencing some `abstract` element) attributes set. Removing the `type` didn't remove the circularity, and since the `abstract` types were simple , it singled-out the `abstract ResponseStructure complexType`. Going back to `ServiceDeliveryBodyGroup`, to see where it descends from (it was the only option left for making anything circular, after going through each part of its contents), quickly revealed the problem.

On another note, it seems to me wrong, that an element may be substituted by an element for which `abstract="true"`. But I don't know that much about XSD. So this might make sense.

Rather than trying to figure that out, I decided to have the `ServiceDeliveryStructure`, rather than basing itself on `ProducerResponseStructure`, to contain the group the latter contains. I would imagine this is the equivalent of using mix-in inheritance rather than true inheritance. AFAIK it should retain the same XML structure, indeed -- obscuring slightly the dependency tree -- but allowing for a full import into Visual Studio, as needed.

In more detail, I replace the following

```
<xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="ProducerResponseStructure">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:group ref="ServiceDeliveryBodyGroup"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="srsName" type="SrsNameType" />
    </xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
```

with the following

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:group ref="ProducerResponseEndpointGroup"/>
    <xsd:group ref="ServiceDeliveryBodyGroup"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="srsName" type="SrsNameType" />
```

(note: `<xsd:annotation/>` tag in original code was left out for brevity)

I will test it, and if it works as expected, I will accept my own answer...